# How to enable the "Fix It" feature in Xcode4?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

The Issue Navigator shows me some issues. One of them is this:

```
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1e100f];
```

> "Magnitude of floating-point constant too large for type 'float';
>   maximum is 1.7014116E+38"

I've heard rumors that Xcode4 can fix obvious things like this with a so called "Fix It" feature. I tried clicking literally everywhere. Right click, left click, Shift click, CMD Shift click, Alt click, Alt CMD Shift click, etc. but whatever I do, no "Fix It" option appears to solve this issue.

Xcode already tells me that I should enter

```
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1.7014116E+38];
```

instead. Perfect situation for "Fix It". What am I supposed to do to awake Fix It? Under which circumstances and where is it supposed to appear, if not here?

Edit: I must use the legacy animation methods because my app needs to stay compatible with iOS 3.2!

Comment: Xcode never said that "you should" use `1.7014116E+38` instead of `1e100f`. All it tells you is that you've gone over the limit for `float` - it doesn't know, or infer, that you want to use whatever the maximum for `float` is. At least, this is my best guess at what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to click on the error icon to see the problem and possible fix for it. Please refer [this](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html#fix-it).